# How to resume Linux VM running after it is suspend from inside?

Tags: linux-kernel, kvm, power-management

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 X86_64 VM within KVM+QEMU.
And I ran a command within the Ubuntu VM to suspend it from inside "sudo systemctl suspend".
After running it, the SSH and virsh console have no responses. So I think the VM is suspended.
In this case, how can I resume the VM running?
I tried 'sudo virsh inject-nmi ubuntu_vm', but it seemed not work.
'sudo virsh list' shows the VM is in running state.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use,

`virsh dompmwakeup ubuntu_vm`

or from qemu monitor,

`system_wakeup`

Comment: It does NOT work, `user@WSJW5V3L3:~$ sudo virsh dompmwakeup ubuntu_vm
error: Domain taow_ubt2004 could not be woken up
error: internal error: unable to execute QEMU command 'system_wakeup': Unable to wake up: guest is not in suspended state
`. This seemd that virsh does NOT think the VM is suspend (although the VM is suspended from inside).

Comment: @wangt13 You should delete the question from stackoverflow and post it to  Unix&Linux or Serverfault, you'll get more answers there I suppose.

Comment: I am not sure what kind of questions should be posted here, and what should be posted into Unix&Linux. I found lots of questions in SO similar to the category I asked. Could you help clairfying the rules of posting question here?

Comment: Mainly dev - programming questions are asked on SO. I'm sure you'd get more answers in either Unix&Linux or Serverfault.